# Could not find method dependenciesInfo() for arguments

Tags: android, dependencies

Could not find method dependenciesInfo() for arguments [build_f58e02lsj5bp8ws7xpexryhuq$_run_closure3@16c6736f] on project ':_09_FruitLinesB' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk true
        includeInBundle true

    }



dependencies {
    implementation project(':andEngine')
    implementation files('libs/StartAppAdMobMediation-1.0.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.5.5.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i see gradle project sync failed